# problem with qemu emulation, "black window!!"

Tags: linux, qemu, arm, emulation

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 x86, a kernel linux-4.9 and I followed [this](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-arm-and-emulate-with-qemu/) tutorial and everything works perfectly, but when I run qemu with:

```
qemu-system-arm -m vexpress -a9 \
-kernel linux-4.9/arch/arm/boot/zImage -m 32 -initrd rootfs.img.gz \
-append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init"
```

The qemu window starts, but it is black, there is no display and it stays like that.

how to correct this problem?

Comment: Is there any output on the serial window? The guide mentions using the `console` kernel parameter at the end of the guide.

Comment: Also, can you try with VNC instead of SDL? I found an SDL-specific bug at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1778182